# Segmentation fault in Boost blocking connect function when no server is present?

Tags: c++, boost, segmentation-fault, boost-asio, destructor

Boost blocking TCP implementation taken from here:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp

Another similar problem, mentioned here
[Boost.Asio segfault, no idea why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009156/boost-asio-segfault-no-idea-why)

I tried checking the destructor order and dependencies as mentioned in the answer but no luck.
Posting relevant code here

edit:: **This MSVC code actually works without segmentation fault. Will be updating code with more relevant info from the failing program.**

main.cpp
{

```
int main(void) {
  int k = Connection_Init();
  return k;
}
```

}

In Connection_Init(), I am calling c.connect(IP, Host, timeout);

**The seg fault occurs while returning from c.connect(), given in Network.cpp**

Network.h
{

```
class client
{
public:
  client()
    : socket_(io_service_),
      deadline_(io_service_)
  {
    // No deadline is required until the first socket operation is started. We
    // set the deadline to positive infinity so that the actor takes no action
    // until a specific deadline is set.
    deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

    // Start the persistent actor that checks for deadline expiry.
    check_deadline();
  }

  int connect(const std::string& host, const std::string& service, tcp::resolver::query& q1,
      boost::posix_time::time_duration timeout)
  {
    // Resolve the host name and service to a list of endpoints.
    //tcp::resolver::query query(host, service);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iter = tcp::resolver(io_service_).resolve(q1);

    // Set a deadline for the asynchronous operation. As a host name may
    // resolve to multiple endpoints, this function uses the composed operation
    // async_connect. The deadline applies to the entire operation, rather than
    // individual connection attempts.
    deadline_.expires_from_now(timeout);

    // Set up the variable that receives the result of the asynchronous
    // operation. The error code is set to would_block to signal that the
    // operation is incomplete. Asio guarantees that its asynchronous
    // operations will never fail with would_block, so any other value in
    // ec indicates completion.
    boost::system::error_code ec = boost::asio::error::would_block;

    // Start the asynchronous operation itself. The boost::lambda function
    // object is used as a callback and will update the ec variable when the
    // operation completes. The blocking_udp_client.cpp example shows how you
    // can use boost::bind rather than boost::lambda.
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, iter, var(ec) = _1);

    // Block until the asynchronous operation has completed.
    do io_service_.run_one(); while (ec == boost::asio::error::would_block);

    // Determine whether a connection was successfully established. The
    // deadline actor may have had a chance to run and close our socket, even
    // though the connect operation notionally succeeded. Therefore we must
    // check whether the socket is still open before deciding if we succeeded
    // or failed.
    if (ec || !socket_.is_open()) {
        cout <<  "send_test_case:connect: Connection could not be established to"
                 << LWIP_IP << " " << LWIP_PORT << endl;
      //throw boost::system::system_error(
            //boost::asio::error::operation_aborted);
          //ec ? ec : boost::asio::error::operation_aborted);
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  }

private:
  void check_deadline(

  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;

  //moving to public access
  public: tcp::socket socket_;

  private: deadline_timer deadline_;
  boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer_;
};
```

}

and Network.cpp 
{

```
 client c;
tcp::resolver::query query(LWIP_IP, LWIP_PORT);


int Connection_Init() {
    cout << "IP: " << LWIP_IP << "and Port:" << LWIP_PORT << endl;
    int status = 1;
    try
    {
        status = c.connect(LWIP_IP, LWIP_PORT, query, boost::posix_time::seconds(POSITIVE_TESTING_CONNECT_TIMEOUT));
    }
    //connection initialization should never fail
    catch(std::exception &e) {
        status = -1;
        std::cerr << __FUNCTION__ << ": " << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    catch(...) {
        status = -1;
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

Comment: Who told you to "post full code"? (Actually you posted _no_ code and I'm not quite sure whether that's better or worse..) http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry.. pressed submit by mistake.

Comment: This still isn't a MCVE though, is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks. Just looked up MCVE. I am new to SO. I just snipped irrelevant parts and pasted. Let me test and update.This is not full code as I mentioned anyway.

Comment: When you joined, which was in fact over a year ago, you were automatically taken through the Tour and the How to Ask pages, which instructed you on forming an MCVE.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry. Probably I overlooked it. Anyway, this example is working.. in the sense no seg. fault. Let me see what differences are there in my non working code. I might just solve it now. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction.